# "No name in module" error from Pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I have a file named `main.py` with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import utils.stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hi from main.py")
    utils.stuff.foo()
```

In the directory with `main.py`, I have a subdirectory named `utils` which has a file named `stuff.py` with the following code:

```
print("hi from stuff.py")

def foo():
    print("foo")
```

If I run `./main.py` from the command line, I get the following output:

```
hi from stuff.py
hi from main.py
foo
```

That is exactly what I expect. However, if I run `pylint main.py`, I get the following output:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module main
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
E:  3, 0: No name 'stuff' in module 'utils' (no-name-in-module)
E:  3, 0: Unable to import 'utils.stuff' (import-error)
E:  7, 4: Module 'utils' has no 'stuff' member (no-member)
```

followed by some more detailed statistics that do not seem relevant to my question. Why is this happening? What can I do to make Pylint aware of `utils/stuff.py`? I am running Python 3.5.2, Pylint 1.6.4 and OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried using flake8 just to compare results?

Comment: There literally is no name `stuff` in `utils` or rather `utils/__init__.py`.  If you run `import utils; utils.stuff`, there will be a name error.  No idea as to the import error.  Maybe a bug, though I would expect one like this to have been caught and corrected.

Comment: @idjaw, I've never heard of flake8. I'll research it and try it when I get a chance.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, I know that `import utils; utils.stuff` won't work. I am curious as to why my code runs without exceptions, but it has errors in Pylint. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in Pylint?

Comment: @EliasZamaria I decided to try to replicate your setup (using pylint), and I'm actually not able to reproduce. What I did actually get, and expected was an unused-import and docstring issue.

Comment: how exactly are you running Pylint on `main.py`? Like what is the exact command you use?

Comment: @idjaw, I got a "convention" message saying `Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)`. I didn't mention that because that is irrelevant to my question.

I also got a warning saying `Unused import utils.stuff (unused-import)`. I am pretty sure it only came up because I am not actually using anything in the `utils.stuff` module. I don't care about that.

I ran into my problem on a big, complex project. The code in this question is a toy example that illustrates my problem without a bunch of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I ran `pylint main.py`. I just updated the question to add some more details.

Comment: @EliasZamaria Right. My mention was ultimately to indicate what the only issues were that came up for me. FWIW we have the same setup as well (OS, versions, etc).

Comment: Pylint is acting as if either A) `utils` is not recognized as a package (does it contain `__main__.py`?) or B) `utils` is not recognized as being in a directory on `sys.path`.  You might try putting `import os, sys; print(os.getcwd(), '\n', sys.path)` in both your `main.py` and pylint's startup file (`pylint/__main__.py`?).

Comment: I just edited my question to I define and actually use something in the `utils` module, to make it more closely resemble a real world situation. In place of the "Unused import" warning, I am getting an error saying `Module 'utils' has no 'stuff' member (no-member)`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, I put a `__main__.py` file in the `utils` directory and it didn't seem to do anything (when I run `main.py` directly or when I run Pylint). I don't see why it would matter whether `utils` is in `sys.path`. If I have to dig into the source of Pylint to diagnose this, then it it is probably not worth my time and effort. I thought this was either something simple that I'm doing wrong, or a well-known bug in Pylint.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need a create `utils/__init__.py`. This will make python aware of the submodule and also allows you to run any code you want to happen on import. If you don't want anything to run then just include a docstring.

Comment: I added an empty file called `__init__.py` in `utils`, and I am no longer getting those errors from Pylint. Thanks.

Comment: I also added the `__init__.py` file it made linter stop complaining, but I had to restart visual studio code for it to recognize the change before it stopped complaining

Comment: I added `__init__.py`  in my utils folder but I got still the error

Comment: You should try to restart (relaunch) after the modifications had been made. I did create the    `__init__.py` but also put in there all the modules that I have in my utils/ and after a restart it seems to work.

Comment: I try to avoid using \_\_init\_\_.py for Python > 3.3.

Comment: "If you don't want anything to run then just include a docstring." Where should the docstring be included?

Comment: @Caridorc the first line of the `__init__.py` should be a docstring. Then put nothing else in the file.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when my function was named start:

```
from views import start
```

It worked when I changed the name of the function.

Answer (score 2):

If the module that you are importing has an error in it, then you will also get this pylint error.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes got this pylint warning in PyCharm. The code works and PyCharm is able to navigate to the imported function if I Ctrl-click on the name.

From https://pycodequ.al/docs/pylint-messages/e0611-no-name-in-module.html

> There can be false positive issues of the type when
>
> - pylint is run with an incompatible python version
> - pylint is run in an environment that misses a depedency of your code (this is more likely to lead to issues of type import-error
>   (E0401))
> - the name you are importing is in turn imported into the target module by a wildcard import

A false positive warning can be **disabled** with a comment:

```
# pylint: disable = no-name-in-module
```

The warning can also be disabled in pyproject.toml section of pylint:

```
[tool.pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']

disable=[
  'no-name-in-module'
]
```