# Defaulting Pylint to run by module instead of file name

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have run into an issue using Pylint with my project in VS Code. It seems that when Pylint is run by default it is looking for the file name rather than the module (`path/to/module.py` as opposed to `path.to.module`). The problem is that this seems to ignore the implicit namespace package. I would prefer to avoid placing `__init__.py` files in every sub directory of the project to resolve this (I have confirmed that works, but it is not a very clean solution). I have also tried adding logic to the `init-hook` in `.pylintrc` to append `path/to/root` to `sys.path`, but this makes no difference.

I have found when running pylint manually in the terminal it works as expected when run by module but gives me `no-name-in-module` and `import-error` when run by file. Example:

**Module:**

```
$ pylint site.tests.common.footer

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

**File:**

```
$ pylint site/tests/common/footer.py
************* Module footer
site/tests/common/footer.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'pytest' in module 'common' (no-name-in-module)
site/tests/common/footer.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'expect' in module 'common' (no-name-in-module)
site/tests/common/footer.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'assert_expectations' in module 'common' (no-name-in-module)
site/tests/common/footer.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'GlobalVariables' in module 'common' (no-name-in-module)
site/tests/common/footer.py:2:0: E0401: Unable to import 'site.pages' (import-error)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -25.71/10 (previous run: -25.71/10, +0.00)
```

My question is whether there is a way to override the default behavior of Pylint to use the former method here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No name in module" error from Pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334643/no-name-in-module-error-from-pylint)

Comment: @Brandon -How to understand "ignore the implicit namespace package."? I run these two methods and the results are very similar, so could you provide us with a minimal code that can reproduce this problem?