Pylint complains about relative imports
Pylint complains about relative importing, however the import works.. I know, that I can easily ignore the warning but thats now what I want..
My project structure
project_root/
├── main.py
├── instruments/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_instrument/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── my_instrument.py

my instruments.__init__.py is empty, however instruments.my_instrument.__init__.py has
from .my_instrument.py import my_function
Inside main.py I'm importing my_function as so:
from instruments.my_instrument import my_function
Which is working, however it does not satisfy Pylint..

No name "my_function" in module "instruments.my_instrument"
Pylint(E0611:no-name-in-module)

Would appreciate help, thnx!

you checked that?

Your (last) import would import from __init__.py but I guess you are trying to import from my_instrument.py. You need another .my_instrument in the from.

@GaTe, actually the comment on this answer helped me... https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184125/21429251
Where it says that simply restarting the Visual Studio Code was needed.. which happened to be the problem in my situation too... I guess it is a duplicated question.. Thanks for quick answering <3
